# Iterate through list and compare values

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

im trying to iterate through a column filled with lists of dates and say if the second date is 10 mins or more than the first date then '1' else '0' and if third date 10 mins or greater than second date then '1' else '0' ect ect.

Im sorry if this has been answered i just cant seem to find any help with this.

Lists are all different sizes. Does anyone know where how i should go about doing something like this?

```
df = df_data_collective.groupBy("customer_id").agg(
    F.expr("collect_list(start_dt)").alias("start_times")
)
```

This outputs the customer id and lists of datetimes likes this

```
['2020-04-02T08:15:50+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:15:53+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:15:56+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:16:01+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:16:07+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:05+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:17+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:30+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:43+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:49+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:22:11+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:22:16+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:02+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:09+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:37+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:36:26+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:25+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:41+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:52+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:18+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:27+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:33+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:49+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:41:03+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:41:29+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:00+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:23+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:57+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:44:43+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:44:49+01:00']
```

I have a very basic knowledge of for loops however still in training and looking to see if anyone can offer any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt_str_list = ['2020-04-02T08:15:50+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:15:53+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:15:56+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:16:01+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:16:07+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:05+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:21:17+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:30+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:21:43+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:49+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:22:11+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:22:16+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:24:02+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:09+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:24:37+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:36:26+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:39:25+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:41+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:39:52+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:18+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:40:27+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:33+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:40:49+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:41:03+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:41:29+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:00+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:42:23+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:57+01:00',
               '2020-04-02T08:44:43+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:44:49+01:00']


dt_list = [datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
           for dt_str in dt_str_list]

minute_10 = timedelta(minutes=10)
flags = [1 if dt_list[i] - dt_list[i-1] > minute_10 else 0
         for i in range(1, len(dt_list))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.split()` method:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

lst = ['2020-04-02T08:15:50+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:15:53+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:15:56+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:16:01+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:16:07+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:05+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:17+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:30+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:43+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:21:49+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:22:11+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:22:16+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:02+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:09+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:24:37+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:36:26+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:25+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:41+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:39:52+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:18+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:27+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:33+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:40:49+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:41:03+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:41:29+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:00+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:23+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:42:57+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:44:43+01:00', '2020-04-02T08:44:49+01:00']

def s(d):
    h,m,s = d.split(':',2)
    h = int(h[-2:])*60*60
    m = int(m)*60
    s = int(s[:2])
    return h+m+s

c = [1 if s(lst[i-1])-s(d) >= 600 and i else 0 for i,d in enumerate(lst)]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, have to convert **`start_dt`** to **`timestamp`** format, then after collecting list, we can apply **`transform(with index as i)`** function with **`unix_timestamp`** to get desired output. (transform is available as of **`spark2.4`**)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.show() #sample dataframe

#+-----------+-------------------------+
#|customer_id|start_dt                 |
#+-----------+-------------------------+
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:15:50+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:15:53+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:15:56+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:16:01+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:16:07+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:21:05+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:21:17+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:21:30+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:21:43+01:00|
#|1          |2020-04-02T08:21:49+01:00|
#+-----------+-------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows


df.withColumn("start_dt", F.to_timestamp('start_dt',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+'SS:SS"))\
  .groupBy("customer_id").agg(F.collect_list('start_dt').alias('start_times'))\
  .withColumn("start_times", F.expr("""transform(start_times,(x,i)-> IF(i>0 and (unix_timestamp(x)-\
                                                                     unix_timestamp(start_times[i-1])>=600),1,0))"""))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|customer_id|start_times                                                                               |
#+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|1          |[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
#+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```